# Find and Replace characters

Tags: sql, oracle

How to Find and Replace characters in a string column
RS & OS ===> D, LS & IS ====> SECTION_ID

Output required

```
1-LS-1991      1-P-1991
1-IS-1991      1-P-1991
1-RS-1991      1- D- 1991
1-OS-1991      1-D-1991
```

I have a column section id which has 1-LS-1991, 1-IS-1991, 1-RS-1991, 1-OS-1991 and multiple records of this all ids I want to replace LS with P and RS with D.

How can I do that?

Comment: LS & IS ==== > P

Comment: I want to do in  Oracle

Answer (score 0):

In MySQl use like below,

`update table_name replace SET Section_Id  = REPLACE( REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Section_Id ,'IS','P') ,'LS','P') ,'RS','D') ,'OS','D');`

May be will look bit weird but it will work.

Comment: 1-LS-1991      
1-IS-1991      
1-RS-1991      
1-OS-1991     This all ids are in one column like Column name:Section Id which has multiple records  (1-LS-1991      
1-IS-1991      
1-RS-1991      
1-OS-1991,1-LS-1991      
1-IS-1991      
1-RS-1991      
1-OS-1991) etc etc

Answer (score 0):

```
select regexp_replace(regexp_replace(LP, '(RS)|(OS)', 'D'), '(LS)|(IS)', 'P') as replaced_input
from
(select '1-LS-1991' as LP from dual
union all
select '1-RS-1991' as LP from dual
union all
select '1-IS-1991' as LP from dual
union all
select '1-OS-1991' as LP from dual)
```

will result in

```
1-P-1991
1-D-1991
1-P-1991
1-D-1991
```

EDIT : Done in Oracle

Answer (score 0):

Permanent update:

```
update myTable SET myColumn  = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(myColumn ,'RS','D') ,'OS','D'),'LS','P'),'IS','P')
```

just display:

```
select REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(myColumn ,'RS','D') ,'OS','D'),'LS','P'),'IS','P') as myColumn from myTable
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be suitable to use `regexp_replace()` with `case-insensitive` option (`i`):

```
with tab( str ) as
(
 select '1-ls-1991' from dual union all
 select '1-IS-1991' from dual union all
 select '1-RS-1991' from dual union all
 select '1-os-1991' from dual 
)
select regexp_replace(
                      regexp_replace(str,'ls|is','P',1,1,'i'),
                     'rs|os','D',1,1,'i') as "Result"
  from tab;



Result
--------
1-P-1991
1-P-1991
1-D-1991
1-D-1991
```